# Accessing related Entities

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have three **Entities** in **CoreData**. `Subject`, `Topic` and `Content`. Each related to another.

[image]

I want to access the data in three different **Views**, a `SubjectView`, a `TopicView` and a `ContentView`.

I try to get the data through a FetchRequest. Here you see the FetchRequest for all topics. It loads **all the data**. But I want to **restrict** it to only load the data for a specific `Subject`:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)])
private var topics: FetchedResults<Topic>
```

The FetchRequest for **subjects** looks like this:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isMajor", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)])
private var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
```

And for the **content** like this:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)])
    private var contents: FetchedResults<Content>
```

Maybe you have a clue how to restructure the FetchRequests so that the data depends on each other.

**UPDATE:**

What `NSPredicate(format: "")` do I need?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you already got a object of Subject that you want to restrict to your Topic? Than you should use reverse relationships. Or do you want to restrict based on a name? Not quiet clear.. what do you fetch first? What do you want to restrict on?

Comment: The SubjectView has a variable `subjects` and the sub view (TopicView) has the variable `subject`.

Comment: You need to use a predicate with your fetch request. Paul Hudson describes doing this here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

Comment: @davidev could you provide an example for the usage of "reverse relationships"?

Comment: @TomHarrington could you give me an example on how to use a predicate in my case? Thanks!

Comment: @Timo If you click on the link I included above, you'll find one.

Comment: another thing ... `For-in loop requires 'NSSet?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?` ....what is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct TopicView: View {
    
    ...

    var subject: Subject
    
    @FetchRequest var topics: FetchedResults<Topic>
    
    init(subject: Subject) {
        self.subject = subject
        self._topics = FetchRequest(entity: Topic.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "subject == %@", subject))
    }

    ...

}
```

Using "predicate". That's it!